# Oracle Apex Dynamic Action Plugin Session Value

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am trying to create a Dynamic Action Type Plugin. In the Dynamic action plugin, one of the custom attribute is of the type **PL/SQL Body returning varchar2** which goes something like this.

```
DECLARE  
    query_string varchar2(4000);  
Begin   
    query_string := 'select firstname, lastname from student where id = '|| :PAGE_ITEM_ID;  
    return query_string;  
END;
```

I found out that when the PAGE_ITEM_ID is updated by any other dynamic action, this dynamic action is still using the old value although the session value is already updated. I think this is because the dynamic action is rendered during the page load and hence uses the value at the time of page load.

Is there a way around this so that the above dynamic action uses the updated value?

Comment: If it was a Region plugin, you would tick the **"Has "Page Items to Submit" Attribute"** attribute in the plugin definition. Doesn't seem to be an option for Dynamic Action plugins, however. Might be worth raising on the Oracle forum.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "Page items to submit" property to send information from the browser to the database (and "page items to return" to send updated session state values back to the browser)

But I'm not sure how this differs in the world of plugins, in your specific context.

Comment: That is for when I implement a dynamic action. Let's say I am implementing a standard("built in") Dynamic Action and running a PL-SQL. It does give me the option of submitting page item. I am building my own plugin and trying to add similar feature.

Comment: I think the answer might be in Martin D'Souza's book on APEX plugins, but I'm not sure where I've put that...